# Simple "If-Then-Else" descent parser in Java (homework)

Tags: java, parsing

There's no code snippets around the web that shows how to parse the ambiguos "if-then-else" grammar (at least some pseudo code would be very worth)

In the following grammar (upper-case non terminals, quoted terminals and other symbols are regular expressions done both with terminals and terminals)

```
STATS ::= (STAT)*
STAT ::= IF_STAT
IF_STAT ::= "if" EXP "then" STAT ("else" STAT)? | EXP
EXP ::= IDENT
IDENT ::= ('a'-'z''A'-'Z')+
```

The if statement is ambiguos infact the following code

```
if a then if b then c else d
```

Can be readed both as

```
if a then{
    if b then 
        c
    else
        d
}
```

or

```
if a then{
    if b then
        c
}
else
    d
```

now. Disambiguating seems simple (given I did it correctly):

```
STATS ::= (STAT)*
STAT ::= IF_STAT
IF_STAT ::= "if" EXP "then" STAT |
             "if" EXP "then" IF_STAT_EX "else" STAT | 
            EXP
IF_STAT_EX ::= "if" EXP "then" IF_STAT_EX "else" IF_STAT_EX | 
            EXP
EXP ::= IDENT
IDENT ::= ('a'-'z''A'-'Z')+
```

However I'm failing to write any working parser that correctly parse the following test cases (each line is a different test)

```
//INPUT                                 //EXPECTED OUTPUT
if x then if y then z else w            if x then (if y then z else w)
if x then y else if z then w else k     if x then y else (if z then w else k)
if x then y else if y then w            if x then y else (if y then w )
if x then if y then z else w else k     if x then (if y then z else w) else k
```

Here's the small class reproducing what I'm missing.

```
public class Parser{

    public List<Stat> parseStats(){
        List<Stat> stats = new List<>();
        while(tokenizer.hasTokens())
            stats.add(parseIf());
        return stats;
    }

    private Stat parseIf(){
        // TODO: what here?
    }

    private Exp parseCond(){
        Exp condition = parseIdent();
        tokenizer.consume( "then" );
        return condition;
    }

    private Exp parseIdent(){
        final Ident name = new Ident( tokeziner.toString());
        tokenizer.moveOnNextToken();
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `tokenizer`? Where did you declare it?

Comment: Does it matters? it's just a string "cutter" that I inject through constructor (omitted to keep the question as short possible but with as much info as needed). It does its works, so get current token string, and ask for next token.